# Finding and Clearing Records from an Index Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I created an association table and made a unique key using the pairing of two foreign keys.

I then had records created in this table upon the creation of an incident (record in another table).  The incident's ID would then be paired up with each of the active items from another table.  Thereby creating an association between the new incident and all active items. The unique key was to prevent the same item from being inadvertently added to the association multiple times.

This worked for awhile, until I cascade deleted some test records.  Now when a new record is created, it throws errors that the ID pairing is violating the Unique key constraints.

I had assume that the deletion of the records would allow for recreation of the records but apparently there is another table somewhere that has as a field value the name of the constraint and as data points the pairings of the IDs.  Since this hidden table still has the old values, I cannot proceed.

What might this table be called, and in what schema?  Additionally, what options might I select on the delete action to also delete the appropriate records from the index table?

Now I'm also getting that that primary key already exists for the association table, but it clearly does not.  Perhaps, I could just drop the table and recreate it, after exporting the few hundreds of currently correct data rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `device_checklist` (
   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `RECORD` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `DEVICE` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `ACTIVE_STATUS` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
   `CHECKBOX` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_DEVICE_KEY` (`RECORD`,`DEVICE`),
   KEY `REC_FK_idx` (`RECORD`),
   KEY `DEVICE_FK_idx` (`DEVICE`),
   CONSTRAINT `DEVICE_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`DEVICE`) REFERENCES `devices` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT `REC_ID_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`RECORD`) REFERENCES `mysql`.`maindbtable` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Odd...when I did a:

```
SELECT * FROM device_checklist
```

and ten ordered the results I got 1018 as the highest ID number.  But when I did a:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM device_checklist
```

I got a 1063 as the highest ID, so I did a:

```
SELECT * FROM device_checklist ORDER BY ID DESC
```

and it finally showed me the records with ID higher than 1018. Almost like MySQL Workbench had cached the previous result set and was using that cache rather than finding the new set.

Comment: No other tables are created automatically like this. Are you sure you deleted the rows from the association table?

Comment: It's possible the index has become corrupted, try using `REPAIR TABLE`.

Comment: The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair

Comment: Check if @Barmar is right about the correct deletion.. Otherwise i think it's better that you also post table structures for all tables involved in this question. `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` and some example data see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)